# Executing PostgreSQL Stored Procedure using Spring Data - JdbcTemplate

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, jdbctemplate

I am trying to call a PostgreSQL Stored Procedure from Spring Data JdbcTemplate. The following are the error and code block. Appreciate if any one can help.

### Stored procedure

```
CREATE or replace PROCEDURE getRecord (
IN in_id INTEGER,
OUT out_name VARCHAR(20),
OUT out_age  INTEGER)
language plpgsql
as $$
BEGIN
   SELECT name, age
   INTO out_name, out_age
   FROM Student where id = in_id;
END
$$
```

### Springboot Code

```
SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall;
dataSource = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(jdbcTemplate).withProcedureName("getrecord");

SqlParameterSource in = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("in_id",24);

try {
    Map<String, Object> out = simpleJdbcCall.execute(in);

    if (out != null){
        System.out.println("A record found");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("No record found");
    }

}
catch (Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

### Error

```
CallableStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [{call getrecord(?, ?, ?)}]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: getrecord(integer) is a procedure
  Hint: To call a procedure, use CALL.
  Position: 15
```

### Note:

The stored procedure is having three parameters - one IN and two Out Parameters.
After going through few tutorials, I had observed that, only in parameter is being passed to the stored procedure call rather than all 3 parameters, because only the first parameter is IN and the rest of two are OUT parameters.
For example:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/springjdbc/springjdbc_stored_procedure.htm
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-jdbc-stored-procedure-examples/

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Follow these steps:

1. modify procedure as follow, creating a function, instead:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION  getRecord (in_id int4)
RETURNS TABLE(out_name character varying, out_age int4)
language plpgsql
as $func$
  SELECT name, age
    FROM Student where id = in_id;
$func$
;
```

2. Call the procedure using `namedParameterJdbcTemplate`:

```
@Autowired
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate namedParameterJdbcTemplate;


[...]

var args = new MapSqlParameterSource();
args.addValue("in_id", 1);
String sql = "select * from getRecord (:in_id)";
var result = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(sql, args);
```